# Help me understand what is happening with this FAIL in my unit test

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing

I have a method that serializes a collection to a file using the XmlSerializer.

```
    public void Save(List<RetryAttempt> retryAttempts)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Create);

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RetryAttempt>));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, retryAttempts);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LocalLogger.LogError("Unable to save retry information to xml file.", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

I then have another method that deserializes the collection back from the file

```
    public List<RetryAttempt> GetRetryAttempts()
    {
        List<RetryAttempt> retryAttempts = new List<RetryAttempt>();

        if (File.Exists(this.fileName))
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Open);

            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RetryAttempt>));
                retryAttempts = (List<RetryAttempt>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LocalLogger.LogError("Unable to read from retry xml file.", ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        return retryAttempts;
    }
```

So far so good (unless anyone spots something glaringly wrong with that code...). However, my unit test for this now fails

```
    [Test]
    public void GetRetryAttempts_AttemptsExist_ListOfAttemptsReturned()
    {
        this.attempt = new RetryAttempt("1234", 4);
        this.attempts = new List<RetryAttempt>() { attempt };
        this.xmlStore = new XmlRetryFileStore(RetryType.Download);
        xmlStore.Save(attempts);

        List<RetryAttempt> savedAttempts = xmlStore.GetRetryAttempts();
        Assert.Contains(attempt, savedAttempts);
    }
```

I would expect the list of my custom object to contain the "attempt" that I serialized to the file. Instead I am getting the following failure.

*Expected: collection containing < MyNamespace.RetryManagement.RetryAttempt >
  But was:  < MyNamespace.RetryManagement.RetryAttempt >*

This message seems to suggest that instead of a collection being returned, just one object was returned. This is obviously not the case - there is a List being returned that only contains one element - I can see the collection in the immediate window and everything looks fine. I can run the test with the debugger and everything seems okay. If I simply create a collection and assert that it contains the element without saving and getting it from XML then it works fine so the point of failure must be around the serialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that your class doesn't implement its own overridden version of `.Equals` method. The contains method would otherwise do a reference check and since you are comparing serialized versions with the original the instances are not the same.

I would suggest implementing this (along with `GetHashCode` so you are able to do comparisons for equality

Comment: I did not realize the .Contains method used .Equals but thinking about it of course it must.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you may be running into is the way objects are compared - in .Net, object equality is handled by comparing whether the variables in question point at the same object in memory.

in this instance, de-serializing is creating a new instance of your list with a new `RetryAttempt`. The new `RetryAttempt` may well contain the same values as the one you serialised (it should) but it will have a different memory address.

Try testing a specific property on the `RetryAttempt`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having those methods write to a file I would recommend you changing the their signature to work with a TextWriter. This way they are more independent of the underlying storage:

```
public void Save(List<RetryAttempt> retryAttempts, TextWriter writer)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RetryAttempt>));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, retryAttempts);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LocalLogger.LogError("Unable to save retry information to xml file.", ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now your test could become:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSerialize()
{
    // arrange
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        this.attempt = new RetryAttempt("1234", 4);
        this.attempts = new List<RetryAttempt>() { attempt };
        this.xmlStore = new XmlRetryFileStore(RetryType.Download);
        this.xmlStore.Save(writer, this.attempts);
    }

    string actual = sb.ToString();
    // TODO: assert on the resulting XML
}
```

Also notice that you shouldn't use the `GetRetryAttempts` method to assert in the unit test of the `Save` method. Those two methods should be separate and have their separate tests.

And the `GetRetryAttempts` method:

```
public List<RetryAttempt> GetRetryAttempts(TextReader reader)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RetryAttempt>));
        return (List<RetryAttempt>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LocalLogger.LogError("Unable to read from retry xml file.", ex.ToString());
    }
    return new List<RetryAttempt>();
}
```

Comment: Good point about the TextWriter actually. Although this is an implementation of an IRetryStore interface so I'm not too worried about using the FileStream here - it is specific to this implementation. But I do like the flexibility it gives, especially with the testing...thanks.

Comment: How would suggest separating the Save and Get methods in the unit tests so I am not using one in testing another one? I'd definitely like to separate these out if possible - my tests should be independent of other tests...

Comment: Take a look at the unit test I proposed for the Save method. There's no call of the Get method.